# Backbone.js fetch method with data option is passing URL params with square brackets

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have the following code to fetch the data for my collection but with specifying what colors should come from the server:

```
fruits = new FruitsCollection();
fruits.fetch({
    data: {color: ['red', 'green']}
});
```

This is what I expect:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/fruits/?color=red&color=green
```

This is what I got:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/fruits/?color[]=red&color[]=green
```

As you can see, for some unknown reason Backbone.js is appending the square brackets to the URL params, instead of having `color=green` I have `color[]=green`

I'm using [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) in the server side and I know I can do a hardcoded fix there, but I prefer to know the logic reason because it is happening and how can I solve it from my javascript.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Backbone uses [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) under the hood for the ajax request so you need to use the `traditional: true` options to use "traditional" [parameter serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
fruits = new FruitsCollection();
fruits.fetch({
    traditional: true,
    data: {color: ['red', 'green']}
});
```

Comment: Worked as expected, this is the answer I wanted. But another question appeared, how you found this option? I can't see it in the documentation.

Comment: In the backbone documentation it is described at the `fetch`  method: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch that you can pass in any of the jQuery.ajax options and the `traditional` from the jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/